# Finding integers to satisfy two inequalities.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Let $a,b,c $  be integers.  We want to prove that there exists  some integers $r,u,s,t$ such that $ru-st=1$ and $$|2art+b(ru+ts)+2csu|\le |ar^2+brs+cs^2|\le |at^2+btu+cu^2|$$

This problem is from: http://tieba.baidu.com/p/2293728953

Comment: Is the term in the middle of the middle "2+brs" or "2brs" (i.e., "two times brs")? Based on my (limited) knowledge of quadratic forms, I would guess that it should be "2brs".

Comment: Yes,I have edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the quadratic form $f(x,y) = ax^2+bxy+cy^2$. The question is equivalent to whether there is a modular transformation $\begin{pmatrix} r & t \\ s & u\end{pmatrix}$ of $f$, call it $g$, where
$$g\left(\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} \right) = f\left(\begin{bmatrix} r & t \\ s & u\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}\right)$$
such that $|c'| \ge |a'| \ge |b'|$ if $g(x,y) = a'x^2+b'xy+c'y^2$.

The answer is positive. Among all the equivalent forms to $f$, take one with smallest $|a|$. By translating with suitable $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & k \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, one can force $b$ to lie in the range $(-|a|, |a|]$, so $|b| \leq |a|$. Then since $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ and $cx^2-bxy+ay^2$ are equivalent, we have $|c| \ge |a|$, so we found a transformation for $f$ such that $|c| \ge |a| \ge |b|$.